# Update UpdatePanel on different user’s web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a web page (aspx). This page has a `button` , a `UpdatePanel` and a `Timer`. Now my problem is as follow suppose 10 users are on this page at the same time and suppose user number 3 and 8 click its button then all user’s UpdatePanel should get updated. What is right way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: The updatepanel uses ajax to communicate with the clients browser and there is no way the individual browsers can know about the state of other browsers. I think you will have to use websockets to push changes to all clients or let the clients check a webservice rather than just a page.

Comment: @faester will you explain `check a webservice rather than just a page`.

Comment: I think it's my stubborn self, but I believe it **is** possible. I provided a brainstorm in code below.

Answer (score 1):

Since each user is running its own copy of the web application so whats happenning on one user's browser can't be notified to the other user. One thing you could do is when one user clicks the button to update, you could save it, whereas all the user application could ping the server may be every 2 secs to know if updation happens and if so updates.

Comment: There is something called GLOBAL which manages all instances ( = Sessions ). Surely that can be used to create some sort of interaction between different sessions ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Global property. On that property, you can put an Observer pattern, and let the visitors subscribe. When you alter the Application property ( shared throughout all Sessions ), you call the Notify() method. The client Notify() method gets called, and there you put functionality to update the UpdatePanel.

**This code is NOT TESTED, it is a guideline**

```
// *** GLOBAL.ASAX
// This collection will contain all the updatepanels that need to be updated
private List<IUpdatePanelClient> _registeredClients = new List<IUpdatePanelClient>();

public static void RegisterClient(IUpdatePanelClient client)
{
    _registeredClients.Add(client);
}
public static void UnregisterClient(IUpdatePanelClient client)
{
    _registeredClients.Remove(client);
}
// Which client is triggering the update call ?
private IUpdatePanelClient _clientUpdating = null;
public static IUpdatePanelClient ClientUpdating
{ 
    get { return _clientUpdating ; } 
    set { _clientUpdating = value; Notify(); }
}
// Notify the clients
public static void Notify()
{
    foreach(IUpdatePanelClient client in _registeredClients)
    {
        client.Update();
    }
}

// *** IUPdatePanelClient.CS
interface IUpdatePanelClient // Interface to make the calls
{
    void Update();
}

// *** Your codepage
public class MyUpdatePanelPage : Page, IUpdatePanelClient // Inherit the interface
{
    public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyUpdatePanelPage.Global.RegisterClient(this);
    }

    public void Btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyUpdatePanelPage.Global.ClientUpdating = this;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        this._updatePanel1.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code has so many issues like accessing `static` method in `page` from `Global.asax`. you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to answer properly. If there is information that you want to keep all users update-to-date on, store that information in a database. When one user edits the data from their user session, whenever other user's get their page refreshed, they will have the most updated data. If you want to have their page refreshed periodically, use a javascript timer.